# Where do I get the Salesforce Marketing Cloud "Public Key" for PGP Encryption?

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption, key, pgp

I remember this used to be "Google-able". For some reason, I can't seem to locate the answer via Google. I have a client that needs to send over their data to Marketing Cloud's SFTP site and they (the client) needs to encrypt it using SFMC's Public Key prior to sending it over. Where can I get this public key to pass to the client?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is what you're after.

https://members.exacttarget.com/Content/Subscribers/SubsLists/publickey.txt